# How to see who has joined a domain / joining a domain clarifications

Tags: windows-domain, windows-server-2012-r2

When you join a domain do you join the **computer** to that domain or the **user** to that domain?

Also is there a simple way to see in Active Directory who has joined the domain?

We are using Windows Server 2012 r2.

Answer (score 4):

User's are created within Active Directory which is like a database for the domain that holds all user and computer objects (as well as other bits).

Computers are joined to the domain, which automatically creates a computer object in Active Directory.

So in a short simple way; users are created, computers are joined. With some exceptions but lets not get complicated :)

As for your last question who has joined the domain? Do you mean who joined a specific PC to the domain or who has a domain account?